# Is writing a guidebook to a work of fiction a copyright violation?

Tags: intellectual-property

Is it a copyright violation to write a guidebook to a work of fiction? For example, there are guidebooks to Tolkien's Middle Earth and to Star Wars, etc.

I would have thought that it is fair use because a guidebook is "commentary". Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

[Fair use](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107) is decided on a case by case basis and involves a multi-factor test.  Just because there is commentary does not necessarily mean the courts will find that it is fair use.  See, for example, [Ty, Inc. v. Publ'ns Int'l, Ltd.](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/summaries/ty-publ'ns-ndiii2004.pdf), where fair use was not found in a collector's guide to Beanie Babies that contained photographs of them.

> The court then rejected defendant’s argument that the photographs were necessary to create a competitive collector’s guide because, even if defendant had a right to produce such a guide, it still copied more of plaintiff’s work than was necessary.